# what does '[+i]' mean in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
function markAnswer(i){
  poll.selectedAnswer = +i;
  try {
    document.querySelector(".poll .answers .answer.selected").classList.remove("selected");
  } catch(msg){}
  document.querySelectorAll(".poll .answers .answer")[+i].classList.add("selected");
  showResults();
}
```

I understand what `[i]` mean in array. However, I don't understand what does `[+i]` mean. I can assume that `[+i]` is related to array, but I don't know why there is `+` sign in front of `i`.

And this code is from YouTube channel called CodingFlag. I watched CodingFlag and found out this code and I try to read and learn something from it, but I can't understand that `[+i]` part.

Comment: `+i` casts the content of `i` into a number

Comment: `+i` converts `i` to a number. It should be completely useless here, because there are no actual numeric indexes in JS - all keys are converted to a string, so `arr[1]` actually addresses the `"1"` key. In some circumstances, there is special treatment for keys that represent non-negative integers, e.g., `"0"`, `"1"`, `"2"`, but again - they are still strings. Doesn't matter whether you use `foo[1]` or `foo["1"]` to access those.